# rewrite nginx index to root

Tags: redirect, nginx

I tried the other solutions on overflow, but those solutions do not work for me.  There is not much documentation with any answers so it is harder to apply outside their specific case.

I already have site.com redirecting to www.site.com with

```
server {
    listen 10.10.10.10;
    server_name site.com;
    rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent;            
}
```

And I want to add a site.com/index redirect to site.com.  Anything I get to work becomes a loop.

EDIT

Based on defenestrate.me's answer and other info I picked up -

The usual config -

```
location / {
        index index.html index.php;
    }
```

Sends root to index.html etc.  So if index.html is redirecting to root this will redirect back to index so an if function is needed as in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just managed to get this working by using the following inside just a server section:

```
if ($request_uri = /index.php) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host;
}
```

I'm not overly proficient in nginx but I'll try to answer your questions (someone please correct me if I'm wrong)

You'd probably have to add it to both the post 80 and port 443 sections for it to work, I don't think adding it to a site-wide listener would work.

You need to keep the index index.html index.php; line as it specifies which default files to load if one isn't specified (navigating to a folder for example)

Comment: it loops because of the index index.html index.php;

Comment: Very strange, in my testing it's been fine with the index set like that. Have all previous methods using rewrites been removed? Could you post the current configuration so we can test the settings you're using?

Comment: I wasnt getting the if statement and why its the key.  index.php was working sitewide, but not index.  Not really sure whats going on there